# How can we achieve the multi recipient shopping cart using ubercart

Tags: ubercart

With [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) we want to develop a multi recipient eCommerce site.

Is there any free open source tool that can achieve this? What method can be used to construct multi recipient functionality.

Comment: Did you discover a way to do this?